# docker hangs on internal connection loopback

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

Kind of new to docker but have a setup with multiple microservices in docker using FastAPI each with their own Postgres DB. Have an issue where I am sending an API request to microservice A, which calls an internal microservice B which works fine, the issue arises when I make an API request to microservice A, which calls microservice B, which sends another API request to back to microservice A to completely unrelated endpoint to fetch some other data type that only exists there, only the connection just hangs on "Starting new HTTP connection" in the docker logs. Not sure where to start to look on how to debug this, any help appreciated.

Tried making multiple simultaneous connections to microservice A, no issues there.

Comment: Based on this information, your setup seems fine and nothing out of the ordinary. So the issue is somewhere else. You need to be more specific on where the issue lies. What connection is failing?
Your question could benefit from more detail and specificity both. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Do internal calls to A from B ever work?